# Unbind and bind driver during startup 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ethernet

My system is running 20.04.3 LTS, and I am using it as a Plex Media Server (amongst other services).  I am using a bonded network for adaptive load balancing on the system.  I am bumping into an issue with the system when it receives a new kernel update.

There are 2 network cards in the system.  One is in a slot (RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller) and the other is onboard (RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller).  The issue I am bumping into is that the RTL8111/8168/8411 does not like the r8169 driver (unpredictable things will happen like not being able to communicate with the internet) so I have to run the following commands to unbind the r8169 driver and bind the r8168 driver:

```
address=$(lspci | awk '/8168/ {print "0000:"$1}')
echo $address | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/unbind
echo $address | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8168/bind
```

After running these commands the driver shows up correctly in the `lshw` command and I don't have any issues when the right driver is set for the right card:

```
terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: c8:3a:35:d6:ec:a0
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair slave=yes speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:25 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:03:05.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 10
       serial: bc:5f:f4:79:66:fe
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic duplex=full latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=twisted pair slave=yes speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:20 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:febffc00-febffcff memory:febc0000-febdffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: bond0
       serial: bc:5f:f4:79:66:fe
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bonding driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic duplex=full firmware=2 ip=10.0.0.220 link=yes master=yes multicast=yes
```

This lasts through reboots just fine until the next kernel update.  But, if I run those exact same commands in a script it tells me "No such device"

```
terrance@Intrepid:~/bin$ sudo ./driver_fix.bsh 
0000:02:00.0
tee: /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/unbind: No such device
0000:02:00.0
tee: /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8168/bind: No such device
```

What would be the best way that I can make this permanent so either it makes this change during startup or it changes only when a kernel update happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you need to create the `unbind` before it runs the `bind` line.  You can add this to a script, then run with with cron at reboot or other things like possibly systemd.

I added the following lines to a script file:

```
address=$(/usr/bin/lspci | awk '/8168/ {print "0000:"$1}')
sh -c "echo $address > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/unbind"
sh -c "echo $address > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8168/bind"
```

Then added the following line to `/etc/crontab`:

```
@reboot     root    /home/terrance/bin/fix_rtl.bsh
```

And now when the system reboots the correct driver is attached to the correct NIC.

```
terrance@Intrepid:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: bc:5f:f4:79:66:fe
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.049.02-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair slave=yes speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:25 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:03:05.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 10
       serial: c8:3a:35:d6:ec:a0
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-35-generic duplex=full latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=twisted pair slave=yes speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:20 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:febffc00-febffcff memory:febc0000-febdffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: bond0
       serial: c8:3a:35:d6:ec:a0
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bonding driverversion=5.13.0-35-generic duplex=full firmware=2 ip=10.0.0.220 link=yes master=yes multicast=yes
```